# Debuging C code ported into Ada using the language feature "pragma IMPORT"

Tags: gdb, ada

It is possible to use gdb in order to debug a C function ported into an Ada executable using the call:

```
pragma IMPORT ( C , My_C_Function,  "my_C_function" );
```

?

I tried to use the following command:

```
gdb -tui -x .init ada_executable
```

Inside the ".init" file,
I placed a break point inside the C file that contains the C function "my_C_function".

E.g.

```
b my_C_function.c:267
```

But when i run gdb, i just see ADA code in the debugger terminal output and no C code(i wonder if there is a way to display the C code debug info in C format?).

Comment: For the targets I've worked with, GDB always switched automatically between C and Ada (except in the dawn of time, when the system GDB didn't support Ada). Does your C function actually run?

Comment: Did you compile with the optimisation off and the debugging on? -0 & -g if I remember correctly!

Comment: I'm using a big script to compile. But i feel confident that im compiling "ada_executable" with: gnatmake -rdynamic -g -i -gnatf -gnatm999999 -j8

Comment: But what are you compiling the C function with?